# Undefined method `^' for String (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I'm very new to Cucumber/Capybara/Ruby/Selenium and I'm just trying to set a simple field with a value.  I'm finding the field with a special selector and then trying to set it:

```
Capybara.add_selector(:filter_field) {xpath { |field_name| ".//div[contains(@class,'#{field_name}')]//input" }}

def fill_in_field(field_name, value)
  field = find(:filter_field, field_name)
  field.set(value)
end
```

> undefined method `^' for "1":String (NoMethodError)
>   ./features/support/ui_interface_react.rb:271:in `fill_in_field'

The error occurs on the line `field.set(value)`.  I know that *value* is a string and *field* is a `#<Capybara::Node::Element>`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the stacktrace for the error, and what driver are you using?

Comment: Do you have more of the stacktrace that would show the line in Capybara?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using selenium, and I'm guessing the field element you're finding is a checkbox, which takes `true` or `false` when calling set, not a string.

Comment: This was indeed the answer.  The xpath I actually had in my code was more complicated than I listed here and resulted in several inputs being selected, the first of which was a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare function in top of file because ruby execute in top to bottom fasion  like this

```
   def fill_in_field(field_name, value)
  field = find(:filter_field, field_name)
   field.set(value)
  end

Capybara.add_selector(:filter_field) {xpath { |field_name| ".//div[contains(@class,'#{field_name}')]//input" }}
```